# Possible to use += with the css top and bottom properties in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Basically I would like to do something like this:

```
$("#whatever").css("bottom", "-=40");
$("#whatever").css("top", "+=40");
```

[I saw an example](http://api.jquery.com/css/) on jQuery's website where they did this with the width, but when I tried it with bottom and top it didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/TUyLs/

Can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: It works fine with jQuery 1.6.2, your jsFiddle was just incorrect.  http://jsfiddle.net/TUyLs/8/

Comment: He also forgot about position: absolute. ;) See my answer

Comment: @dotweb: It works fine without `position: absolute;`.

Comment: There needs to be a default JS library setting, at least for registered users, grrr...

Comment: @BoltClock: Thought that so many times. :P If it doesn't come with the new version, I'll be making a chrome extension for that.

Comment: @Rocket: Misstake by me. Look at his CSS, he declared it as relative, which also works. ;) Static won't work tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/TUyLs/3

Yes, it work's. Make sure to insert jQuery (you inserted mootools). Also the element needs to be positioned absolute, in ordner to use top and left. Without declaring it as absolute, it'll be static, which means you won't be able to position it static.

// BTW, just a tip: You don't need to use document.ready on jsfiddle in your example. JSfiddle is inserting that automatically. (Under 'use framework': 'onLoad')

Comment: position does not need to be absolute. at least in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/TUyLs/12/

Comment: Oh, I didn't see. Look at his CSS, he declared it as relative, which also works. ;) Static won't work tho.

Comment: Never mind. ;) You should use a JavaScript debugger next time tho.

Answer (score 0):

it works, you had some other errors and you were using MooTools

http://jsfiddle.net/TUyLs/10/

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in jQuery 1.6.2.  Your jsFiddle was incorrect.

You selected MooTools, not jQuery.  Also, `#down` was not an element.

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TUyLs/11/